# the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

help me.. i'm new in visual basic....

when i'm running the update it shows the error 
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Macky\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Marcelo 2.2.3\Marcelo\bin\Debug\Students\MIC953867.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

my code is this

```
Public Sub copingfile()
    If inFileName = Nothing Then
        studpic.Image = Nothing
    Else
        outFileName = inFileName
        pos = inFileName.LastIndexOf(".")
        If (pos > 0) Then
            outFileName = outFileName.Substring(0, pos)
        End If
        outFileName += ".jpg"
        str = Application.StartupPath & "\Students\"
        saveJPEGFile.FileName = str & StudID.Text & ".jpg" '& outFileName
        fil1.Copy(inFileName, saveJPEGFile.FileName, True) 'the error shows here...
        outFileName = saveJPEGFile.FileName()
    End If

End Sub
```

I can save new student information with picture.. but when it comes in updating the picture these codes didn't work......

Comment: Be sure to accept the correct answer and to up-vote any answer that helped you, because it helps future visitors see how the problem was resolved. You always want to keep your accept % as high as you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
 fil1.Copy(inFileName, saveJPEGFile.FileName, True)
```

You're attempting overwrite a file that's open or being used. If the file is open in a viewer/editor, then it can't be copied over. Either you opened it manually, or did so through code and it's still "attached" to something running.

If it's not open in a window, try stopping your code and deleting that file manually. If you can, it's pretty obvious something in code is still using it when you get to the line that errored. You'll need to figure out where that file is still being used (Open stream somewhere? Open in VS, itself?), as it doesn't appear to be in the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to show more code, you are using variables not in your code listing.  Plus you do not show the code that originally saves your image.

But here is my guess...are you sure you closed the file when you saved it for the first time?  You cannot generally copy to, or from, a file that is open.

(Files can be opened as shared, but I don't think you are doing that).

Post more code if you get a chance.